# How to use scipy's leastsq to solve for an array?

Tags: python, scipy

Is there anyway we can use Scipy's leastsq solver (or any other function in python) to find an array instead of a vector?

Basically, I want to find `C` that minimizes function `my_func`. I think one way is to convert `C` to a vector and rewrite the function `my_func` such that the unknowns are a vector. But, is there a better way?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import leastsq


def my_func(C, x, y):
    return y - C.dot(x)


x_data = np.array([2, 3, 4])
y_data = np.array([20, 30])

starting_guess = np.ones((2, 3))
data = (x_data, y_data)


result = leastsq(my_func, starting_guess, args=data)
print result

solution = result[0]
print solution
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `flatten()` and `reshape()` from the `numpy` library to go back and forth between 1d and 2d arrays. As for the minimization itself, I suggest `scipy.optimize.minimize()`.

Please note that the difference between two vectors is a vector (I am referring to `v = y - C.x` here), therefore you need the norm to convert this into a metric that you can minimize. Below, you find a good example on how to code this:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize


def my_func(C_flat, x, y):
    # print(np.linalg.norm(y - np.dot(C_flat.reshape(2, 3), x), 2))
    return np.linalg.norm(y - np.dot(C_flat.reshape(2, 3), x), 2)

x_data = np.array([2, 3, 4])
y_data = np.array([20, 30])

C0   = np.ones((2, 3))
data = (x_data, y_data)

result = minimize(my_func,  C0.flatten(), args = data)
print(result)

solution = result["x"].reshape(2,3)
print(solution)
```